# mailx function is not working

Tags: linux, email, unix, mailx

I am trying to use mailx function to send an e-mail to my personal email address.But I never received an email.Can someone help me pls. Here is my command below.

```
PRI_EMAIL_SUBJECT="Some Blah Blah"
PRI_EMAIL_ADDRESS="bobby.teja@gmail.com"
PRI_EMAIL_BODY="$PRI_SETS_RAN_SUCSFL_CNT no. of sets ran successfully."

echo "Sending e-mail"
mailx -s $PRI_EMAIL_SUBJECT $PRI_EMAIL_ADDRESS < $PRI_EMAIL_BODY
echo
```

Comment: add `-v` to `mailx` to see progress messages and find out where it's going...

Comment: First run it on command line and test : echo "something" | mailx -v -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perfectly works.

```
 echo "something" | mailx -v -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect a string.  `mailx <$FOO` expands the variable `FOO` and attempts to find a file named like that.  But since you (presumably) do not have a file named `3 no. of sets ran successfully.` you get a redirection error, and the command fails.

To actually send the contents of the variable as email, try

```
echo "$PRI_EMAIL_BODY" | mailx
```

(or maybe use a here document).

Answer (score 0):

Use the -d option of mailx for debug output. This may indicate an issue with the mail transport.

```
mailx -d -s $PRI_EMAIL_SUBJECT $PRI_EMAIL_ADDRESS < $PRI_EMAIL_BODY
```